# Remove explicit zero values from sparse matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

Is it possible to remove explicit zero value from sparse matrix in Julia?

Namely, I want to convert `a=sparse([1],[1],[0])` into `b=spzeros(1,1)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes: see [`dropzeros`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/arrays/#Base.dropzeros):

```
julia> a=sparse([1],[1],[0])
1×1 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64,Int64} with 1 stored entry:
  [1, 1]  =  0

julia> dropzeros(a)
1×1 SparseMatrixCSC{Int64,Int64} with 0 stored entries
```

Or you can do it in place (modifying `a`) with `dropzeros!`.